# Output of the following expression

Tags: java

We have `137/42 == 0 && 137/0 == 42`

I have to find the output of the following code in Java.

So 137/42 is 3 and now I have 3 ==0 && 137/0 ==42

First of all what does 3==0 result in ? Also since diving by zero results in an error how come we have 137/0==42?

and I know && means AND but what does that result in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `3 == 0` is `false` and the boolean AND (`&&`) operator is short circuited, the right operand (`137/0 ==42`) won't be evaluated when the first operand is `false`, so the exception won't be thrown and the entire expression will be evaluated to `false`.

Comment: Oh my god I was too focused in finding a number as an answer and didnt think of this.Thank youuu!